# Mongo FindOne and interface{}

Tags: mongodb, go

edit: solved, see first answer. Should have really noticed that while I was creating this example..

I'm trying to create a function that takes an interface instead of a specific type and calls the FindOne function. Does anyone know why the printFirstTrainerByInterface function does not work properly?

I'm using the official Go Mongo-Driver and sample snippets from [mongodb-go-driver-tutorial](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-go-driver-tutorial).

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)

type Trainer struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
    City string
}

var db *mongo.Database

func main() {
    opts := options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost:27017")
    client, err := mongo.Connect(context.TODO(), opts)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    err = client.Ping(context.TODO(), nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    db = client.Database("test")
    insertTestDocument()

    var result Trainer
    printFirstTrainer(result)

    var result2 Trainer
    printFirstTrainerByInterface(&result2)
}

func insertTestDocument() {
    ash := Trainer{"Ash", 10, "Pallet Town"}
    res, err := db.Collection("trainers").InsertOne(context.TODO(), ash)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Inserted a test document: ", res.InsertedID)
}

func printFirstTrainer(result Trainer) {
    collection := db.Collection("trainers")
    err := collection.FindOne(context.TODO(), bson.M{}).Decode(&result)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Found a single document: %+v\n", result)
}

func printFirstTrainerByInterface(result interface{}) {
    collection := db.Collection("trainers")
    err := collection.FindOne(context.TODO(), bson.M{}).Decode(&result)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Found a single document: %+v\n", result)
}
```

Output:

```
Inserted a test document:  ObjectID("5e8216f74f41a13f01061d61")
Found a single document: {Name:Ash Age:10 City:Pallet Town}
Found a single document: [{Key:_id Value:ObjectID("5e8216f74f41a13f01061d61")} {Key:name Value:Ash} {Key:age Value:10} {Key:city Value:Pallet Town}]
```

Comment: What is the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing in the address of the struct you want to decode into as an interface. You have to pass that as the argument to decode, not the address of the interface. Try:

```
err := collection.FindOne(context.TODO(), bson.M{}).Decode(result)
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. I already thought that the solution must be quite simple.. Why this didn't work, I don't understand yet tbh but at least I know that I have to take a closer look at the pointer arithmetic in go again (originally coming from java).

Comment: `result` is a pointer to the struct. `&result` is pointer to the interface that has a pointer to the struct. When you decode to `&result`, you overwrite the pointer in the interface, create a new map[string]interface{}, and decode into that.

Comment: This means that a struct that is re-declared as an interface implicitly becomes a pointer? That's really a bit different than I expected when you come up with the idea of polymorphism from other languages. But well, I'll take a closer look at the pointers again and many thanks for the quick response (btw: I actually put some effort into research before I asked here)

Comment: No, that's not the case. You pass in a pointer to struct, but you discarded that by passing the pointer to interface. What you did is equivalent to declaring a `var result interface{}` in your function. For a simpler case, consider `f(i *int)`. What you did is similar to assigning `i` instead of `*i`.

Comment: Okay, now I see it. That wasn't my original code but I created the example for the question here and that's where I really should have noticed it. Sorry about that.